# R xts time series extend recursively

Tags: r, date, time-series

I have an `XTS` time series, and I would like to calculate the future values (2018-04-01 onwards) based on the previous value `x[t]=x[t-1]*1.01`.
Is it possible without having to do loops?

```
            FRA.GDPV.Q

2017-01-01 2.217110e+12
2017-04-01 2.232964e+12
2017-07-01 2.247932e+12
2017-10-01 2.263204e+12
2018-01-01 2.272640e+12
2018-04-01           NA
2018-07-01           NA
2018-10-01           NA
2019-01-01           NA
```

Comment: See this: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roll/roll.pdf

Answer (score 0):

In this case it's possible since you're basically multiplying the same value (last_value) times 1.01^1, 1.01^2, ...

```
mydata <- rnorm(10)  # sample data
last_value <- mydata[length(mydata)]  # last value

N=4  # will add 4 more values
fv_factors <- 1.01^(1:N)

new_values <- last_value*fv_factors  # computes new values
mydata <- c(mydata,extended_values)  # adds new values to mydata

# Comparing with loop
new_values2 <- c(last_value,numeric(4))  # Same as above
for (i in 2:(N+1)) {
  new_values2[i] <- new_values2[i-1]*1.01
}

round(new_values,4)==round(new_values2[-1],4)  # Same result
```

The rounding isn't necessary, you do get the same values with both methods.

> ```
> > round(new_values,4)==round(new_values2[-1],4)
> [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
> ```

Comment: Thank you this works but sorry i have over simplified my problem in the real life i have equation like x[t]=x[t-1]*1.01+0.1*y[t]
where y is another time series with values for the whole period

Comment: Chances are you won't be able to get rid off the for loop, if you're worried about speed it might be worth taking a look at the Rcpp package : you can write the loop in c++ and call it from R.